# Reusing browser/tab in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, browser

I am using Process.Start() to open a URL and it's great for a one-time use but if opening multiple URLs it creates either a new instance of the default browser or uses a new tab. I need to use the original tab.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Internet Explorer, you will need to reference the `shdocvw.dll` COM component located, by default, at `c:\windows\system32\shdocvw.dll`. This COM component contains a `ShellWindows` object that you can use to determine if there is a running instance of Internet Explorer or not, like this:

```
Dim internetExplorerInstances As New ShellWindows()

Dim foundIE As Boolean = False
For Each ie As InternetExplorer In internetExplorerInstances
If ie.Name = "Windows Internet Explorer" Then
        ie.Navigate(ur, &H800)
        foundIE = True
        Exit For
    End If
Next

If Not foundIE Then
    ' Either do nothing or use Process.Start with a new browser instance
End If
```

For the other browsers, you are, unfortunately,out of luck, programmatically.

Comment: Karl, I ran across this and it seems indeed helpful. But my question is how to implement this? Can you provide a visual? Lastly, are any `Imports` needed to get this to work? I used your model changing the variable names, but the `New` object instances are throwing back errors, saying that I should use `HtmlWindows` instead of `ShellWindows()`. Please advise. Thanks!